# Object reference not set to an instance of an object in TempData

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(EmployeeEntry employeeentry)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                EmployeeEntry employeesales = new EmployeeEntry();
                employeesales.stock_id = employeeentry.stock_id;
                employeesales.quantity = employeeentry.quantity;
                employeesales.total = employeeentry.total;
                employeesales.employeeid = (int)TempData["Name"];

                db.EmployeeEntries.Add(employeesales);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            ViewBag.stock_id = new SelectList(db.AddProduct, "stock_id", "Product_name", employeeentry.stock_id);
            return View(employeeentry);
        }
```

This is my code,I'm getting error while convert TempData into integer.TempData["Name"] contains the Id of the Employee who is logged in .

```
 var Result = from a in db.login where a.userName == login.userName && a.Password == login.Password select a.login_id;
                    TempData["Name"] = Result.Single();

                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "EmployeeHome");
```

I Understand TempData["Name"] doesn't have values .How do i Solve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TempData is used to pass data from current request to subsequent request (means redirecting from one page to another).

So in your case Tempdata[“Name”] only available in current action and Index action of the EmployeeHome Controller.

So you need Session[“Name”] in place of Tempdata[“Name”]

**Like :**

```
var Result = from a in db.login where a.userName == login.userName && 
             a.Password == login.Password select a.login_id;
Session["Name"] = Result.Single();
return RedirectToAction("Index", "EmployeeHome");
```

**and another action**

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(EmployeeEntry employeeentry)
    {
    …
    employeesales.employeeid = (int)Session["Name"];
```